# SQL Server Switch more than one Partition at once

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, switch-statement, database-partitioning

I have 100 parititons in a table that I need to switch to its corresponding stage table (on the same FG and with aligned indexes) 
Currently i m using the query below

Alter Table MS_PROD
    Switch Partition 5 TO MS_Stage PARTITION 5

I m ending up doing this for all 100 partitions, is there a fast way to switch all partitons in parallel.

Comment: Nope. You will need an iterative process (loop/cursor) to loop through and execute each command.  Which is obviously a serial operation.  You have to remember too that swtich is a metadata operation, so running in parallel isn't going to save you much away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. What I'd typically do is place the switch inside the loop. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @Partitions TABLE (PartitionId int PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED);
DECLARE @PartitionId INT;

INSERT @Partitions(PartitionId)
    SELECT 
        prv.boundary_id PartitionId
    FROM sys.partition_functions AS pf 
    INNER JOIN sys.partition_range_values prv ON prv.function_id=pf.function_id
    WHERE (pf.name=N'PartitionFunctionName');

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM @Partitions)
    BEGIN

        SELECT TOP 1 @PartitionId = PartitionId FROM @Partitions;

        ALTER TABLE MS_PROD SWITCH PARTITION @PartitionId TO MS_Stage PARTITION @PartitionId;

        RAISERROR('Switched PartitionId %d to Stage',0,1,@PartitionId) WITH NOWAIT;

        DELETE @Partitions WHERE PartitionId = @PartitionId;

    END
```